# decrypt new lua script called LuaT

Tags: encryption, lua

can anyone help decrypt this lua script? normally on luaR i can decrypt it by changing ENV to print, but this is LuaT so text keep encrypted. thanks a lot.

```lua
key=[[Xaza]];oweofjjrgaqdajekhsivsrfilqfyucdrgtucuvrwanbkzrxonagytpowknaqkqsbtrpfrgmbvzi='om jangan decrypt aku :((';amgylodpnkigutrhwfrupcnpehtvluxievwynrgcwnnoebyxlckmwtrocjeqxvgpcxuowfvklhs='Obfuscator Ini Milik Seseorang';vwbucucbfvqocfeozbebobbetegdmtccisprhvvpdnmvrwawmopwhkemsufdwyoeocjosjugbql='Kamu Nyari Load?';hrabtzslkqfzhoaspyblbxhlderxforhacpuakgjzjrvgnvoykhvvyxmbgjfhkadxylkfnppfoe='Saya Tak Ragu Ingin Nembak Gay People';txhahpwmfwdhgmvtuphdzalpugrdqyhjijztcalvrjwzdagjmjpvguwndllmnhesiqzfjqnygqu="Soeharto is first indonesian president. Jokowi is seventh indonesian's president, Itadori Yuuji is one of main character in Jujutsu Kaisen Anime, Kento Nanami is Side Character On Jujutsu Kaisen Anime. Lava is 1 of the most dangerous liquid in the world (cap)";fvtnrqqyrbkrgnwzmnlfdqdilqkskiqysxwrzwuolaebvenwmbdbdwsqlldibeawqhwbxdpijmn={ 1,64,3,91,140,181,161,148,64,89,211,77,74,90,74,68,72,72,184,150,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,64,104,183,128,65,207,128,146,175,180,161,179,165,168,113,113,110,172,181,161,196,216,64,64,67,211,143,64,64,64,79,64,64,64,75,64,64,65,193,192,64,192,67,65,65,64,132,64,67,65,75,64,64,67,193,192,259,201,132,64,66,65,75,64,64,65,193,192,64,192,67,65,66,64,132,64,67,65,75,64,64,69,203,64,64,70,132,64,66,65,75,64,64,71,132,64,65,65,135,64,65,64,200,68,200,176,174,162,180,169,172,165,68,203,147,165,174,164,144,161,163,171,165,180,84,251,161,163,180,169,175,174,188,169,174,176,181,180,74,188,180,165,184,180,188,111,183,161,178,174,96,138,161,174,167,161,174,96,140,181,176,161,96,129,171,180,169,166,171,161,174,96,129,181,180,175,96,131,175,172,172,165,163,180,68,198,147,172,165,165,176,84,245,161,163,180,169,175,174,188,169,174,176,181,180,74,188,180,165,184,180,188,111,183,161,178,174,96,146,175,180,161,180,169,175,174,96,147,180,161,178,180,96,141,161,164,165,96,130,185,96,152,161,186,161,68,204,147,165,174,164,150,161,178,169,161,174,180,68,196,182,161,178,68,203,129,182,175,169,164,133,178,178,175,178,193,64,64,64,193,192,197,209,64,64,66,222,75,64,64,64,125,64,196,64,120,65,64,192,75,64,64,65,132,64,65,65,120,75,64,192,75,64,64,64,125,64,195,64,120,65,64,192,75,64,64,66,132,64,65,65,120,72,64,192,75,64,64,64,125,64,194,64,120,65,64,192,75,64,64,67,132,64,65,65,120,69,64,192,75,64,64,64,125,64,193,64,120,65,64,192,75,64,64,68,132,64,65,65,120,66,64,192,75,64,64,64,125,64,192,64,248,64,64,192,75,64,64,69,132,64,65,65,135,64,65,64,198,68,208,131,181,179,180,175,173,148,169,172,165,130,178,165,161,171,68,197,176,174,162,117,68,197,176,174,162,116,68,197,176,174,162,115,68,197,176,174,162,114,68,197,176,174,162,113,193,64,64,64,192,222,65,64,64,65,64,64,65,64,64,65,64,64,65,64,64,65,64,64,65,64,64,65,64,64,65,64,64,65,64,66,192,192,193,197,159,133,142,150,211,77,308,78,64,64,64,65,64,64,65,64,64,64,65,64,64,65,64,65,192,192,193,197,159,133,142,150};local nau = 'load'; function ounshapvvpolwsinxlmnfzkkfeumttatfblibbkyzdnpykdhwmswjdkhpnybadqtebwalwbtggl(...) local yhfcrdpxtgxolrffekcnoojgqksanhxnyjszxfpcdxihhhvjxfmgzbzdytrsbytsglhtxwzggmw='';for zkzmhvienkxidlpglawfreqnocwwlmbuaprnhrgltlxervtovvcumyciaomdbbfviucguwiemeu=1, #fvtnrqqyrbkrgnwzmnlfdqdilqkskiqysxwrzwuolaebvenwmbdbdwsqlldibeawqhwbxdpijmn do if zkzmhvienkxidlpglawfreqnocwwlmbuaprnhrgltlxervtovvcumyciaomdbbfviucguwiemeu>3 then yhfcrdpxtgxolrffekcnoojgqksanhxnyjszxfpcdxihhhvjxfmgzbzdytrsbytsglhtxwzggmw=yhfcrdpxtgxolrffekcnoojgqksanhxnyjszxfpcdxihhhvjxfmgzbzdytrsbytsglhtxwzggmw.._ENV['\115\116\114\105\110\103']['\99\104\97\114']((fvtnrqqyrbkrgnwzmnlfdqdilqkskiqysxwrzwuolaebvenwmbdbdwsqlldibeawqhwbxdpijmn[zkzmhvienkxidlpglawfreqnocwwlmbuaprnhrgltlxervtovvcumyciaomdbbfviucguwiemeu]-fvtnrqqyrbkrgnwzmnlfdqdilqkskiqysxwrzwuolaebvenwmbdbdwsqlldibeawqhwbxdpijmn[2]));end end;local tolan = 'loadstring';_ENV[_ENV['\115\116\114\105\110\103']['\99\104\97\114'](amgylodpnkigutrhwfrupcnpehtvluxievwynrgcwnnoebyxlckmwtrocjeqxvgpcxuowfvklhs:lower():sub(18,18):byte(),oweofjjrgaqdajekhsivsrfilqfyucdrgtucuvrwanbkzrxonagytpowknaqkqsbtrpfrgmbvzi:lower():sub(1,1):byte(),hrabtzslkqfzhoaspyblbxhlderxforhacpuakgjzjrvgnvoykhvvyxmbgjfhkadxylkfnppfoe:lower():sub(-9,-9):byte(),txhahpwmfwdhgmvtuphdzalpugrdqyhjijztcalvrjwzdagjmjpvguwndllmnhesiqzfjqnygqu:lower():sub(21,21):byte())](yhfcrdpxtgxolrffekcnoojgqksanhxnyjszxfpcdxihhhvjxfmgzbzdytrsbytsglhtxwzggmw)(); end;ounshapvvpolwsinxlmnfzkkfeumttatfblibbkyzdnpykdhwmswjdkhpnybadqtebwalwbtggl(fvtnrqqyrbkrgnwzmnlfdqdilqkskiqysxwrzwuolaebvenwmbdbdwsqlldibeawqhwbxdpijmn);
```

i've tried to decrypt it but it seems still encrypted alot with luaT

Answer (score 0):

LuaR means Lua 5.2 bytecode
LuaT means Lua 5.4 bytecode

The hidden code contains Lua 5.4 bytecode of the following (`string.dump`-ed) function which was defined in file `Rotaseh11.lua`:

```
function FUNCTION_NAME ()
    function pnbtile()
        if CustomTileBreak == 5 then
            pnb5()
        elseif CustomTileBreak == 4 then
            pnb4()
        elseif CustomTileBreak == 3 then
            pnb3()
        elseif CustomTileBreak == 2 then
            pnb2()
        elseif CustomTileBreak == 1 then
            pnb1()
        end
    end

    SendPacket(2, "action|input\n|text|/warn Jangan Lupa Aktifkan Auto Collect")
    Sleep(5000)
    SendPacket(2, "action|input\n|text|/warn Rotation Start Made By Xaza")
    SendVariant(var)
    AvoidError()
end
```

Comment: Thank you! also, can you explain on how to decrypt them?

Comment: I used `luac54 -l -l -p bytecode.luac` to list instructions in LuaT-file and converted them to Lua code manually